Can C/C++ compiler generate an immediate + relocation instead of a load for extern const variables
See example here: https://godbolt.org/z/TTbEf6GaK
I would hope that the compiler can generate something like:
mov eax, <dummy value with relocation on it>
add eax, 42
ret

and then when linking, resolve this relocation with the value of the constant that it sees in another TU.
Is there any way we can make it do such a thing, or a technical limitation that explains why it isn't done?

What is your question? [rip + something@GOTPCREL] is that <dummy value with relocatoin on it>... this is what the linker can use to replace it with either an address later.  Having said that, if you want the behavior you describe. Put this in a header file of the other TU inline constexpr std::uint32_t something = 42; and use that (side note rax is the 64 bit equivalent of eax)

mov     rax, qword ptr [rip + something@GOTPCREL] is a load. I want it to become "move a constant to rax" instruction after relocation is done

It looks like a load now, it doesn't have to be that after linking.  Linkers can optimize too. So to be sure you should inspect the assembly after linking

I tried linking together two TUs, one like this and another where I supply the constant, but it still remained a load.
I'm sure if I did some fancy LTO it could optimize away that thing entirely, but it's still surprising that the compiler is generating suboptimal code even with a basic linker in this case.

const isn't strong enough for that, the compiler has to assume that that value can change.

Optimization needs context and meta data, most of which is already lost at link time. Because instruction reordering or replacement can eventually change the execution results. Neither compiler, nor linker can guess the intended optimizations in absence of proper markers. inline declaring extern objects is one way to inform the compiler of extra requirements.

This example is a proxy for a far more complex RL situation, where these "constants" are known only at load time (there is a custom-made loader where some of the assets are proprietary binaries, and the constants are the addresses of certain things in memory after they were mapped). I was hoping I can resolve some relocations after mapping all the sections and then not to have the code load any "known constants" from memory when it runs.

This does work properly if the "constant" in question is a function address.
It may also be possible to reliably produce the relocation construct I want in LLVM IR (in the RL scenario I am in, there is code generation directly in IR, so I don't need to adhere to the behaviors/assumptions of a C compiler).
The situation in the original question seems to depend on what C/C++ compilers are allowed / not allowed to assume about just how "const" a const extern variable really is. Thanks everyone for the comments.
